# Is it possible to create custom virtual device using genymotion?

Tags: android, emulation, genymotion, import-contacts

I am wondering if its possible to transfer my actual phone's contacts/phonebook to genymotion virtual device and save it to be reused? Or is there a way to transfer them everytime the emulator is started?

My purpose if to test my app on emulator with real phonebook.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have couple of options

- Create a vCard file and put it on SD card; Click import in the contact app "People" (see below screenshot)
- Or better, create an email/exchange account if available, so the contacts can be backed up. Create/Login with this account using the "Sign in to an account", all your contacts will be synced up.

[image]